# Pass struct property as a generic type

Tags: ios, swift, generics, enums

So I currently have a struct that takes an enum as a type. Below is the struct with the property itemType.

```
struct FormPickerItem: FormItem {
    let id: String
    var title: String
    let itemType: Any.Type
    var margin: UIEdgeInsets
    var size: CGSize?
}
```

The structure of my enum is as followed.

```
enum UserGoal {
    case all
    case buildMuscle
    case strength
    case none
}

extension UserGoal: EnumItem {

    typealias RawValue = String

    init?(rawValue: RawValue) {
        switch rawValue {
        case "All": self = .all
        case "Build Muscle": self = .buildMuscle
        case "Strength": self = .strength
        case "None": self = .none
        default: return nil
        }
    }

    var rawValue: RawValue {
        switch self {
        case .all: return "All"
        case .buildMuscle: return "Build Muscle"
        case .strength: return "Strength"
        case .none: return "None"
        }
    }
}
```

This struct is created using the following, as you can see itemType is the enum type that I'm passing through.

```
FormPickerItem(id: "userGoals", title: "Goals", itemType: UserGoal.self, margin: UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 30, bottom: 0, right: 30), size: nil)
```

`EnumItem` is a protocol that all enums are subclassing so that I can easily pass any Enum as a generic type within a custom class that I have. So the issue that I'm currently having is that I can't pass the property within my struct as the generic type.

```
func configure(with formPickerItem: FormPickerItem, atIndex index: Int = 0, toolBarType: ToolBarType? = .standard, delegate: FormTextFieldDelegate?) {
    self.formPickerItem = formPickerItem
    self.index = index
    self.toolBarType = toolBarType
    self.delegate = delegate

    if loftyPicker == nil {

        loftyPicker = LoftyPicker<formPickerItem.itemType>(index: index, title: formPickerItem.title, applyBottomBorder: true, parentView: self.contentView, loftyDelegate: self)
        contentView.addSubview(loftyPicker!)
        applyConstraints()
    }
}
```

And the LoftyPicker class is declared like so.

```
final class LoftyPicker<Item: EnumItem>: LoftyBaseTextField, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource, LoftyToolBarDelegate {
....
}
```

I'm getting the following error `Use of undeclared type 'formPickerItem'`. Is this possible in swift? If not how can I pass an enum type into a class?

Comment: Is that supposed to be a lowercase F?

Comment: @meggar yes formPickerItem is a parameter from a function that is off type FormPickerItem

Comment: You didn't define `LoftyPicker` in your question

Comment: You need to show the code in more contex; where is the *type* `formPickerItem` declared?

Comment: @Paulw11@Carpsen90 I've added more context now

Comment: `formPickerItem` is not a type.  `FormPickerItem` is a type. I think you are asking Swift to use the type that is provided by `formPickerItem.itemType` at runtime, but that won't work. The Swift compiler needs to be able to determine the type at compile time. You probably want to look at declaring a protocol that various types can adopt rather than using generics in this case, or possibly a factory pattern with subclasses